Not able to access a method declare in one fragment from another fragment
I am fairly new to the concept of fragments. I am making a TodoList app using tab layout. I have 2 fragments, one by the name 'RecyclerViewFragment' which contains all the logic about tasks being shown and also has a floating action button that I am using to access another fragment by the name 'bottomSheetFragment' to enter a new task to my recyclerView.
I hava method declare in the "RecyclerViewFragment" by the name "appendToList" that is used to add any new task to the RecyclerView.
Now how can I access that method from 'bottomSheetFragment'.
I tried to implement an interface and implemented it to bo
public interface TaskDialogListener {
    void onTaskAdded(String taskText, long generatedId);
}


But this did not work.

you can use ViewModel
